# Setup a scala.js cross compiled library

Tags: scala, cross-platform, publish, scala.js

I have a small Scala library that I want to make use of in a Scala.js application: https://github.com/fbaierl/scala-tarjan

For that reason, I have decided to create a cross-compiled library that compiles to both Scala.js and Scala JVM: https://github.com/fbaierl/scalajs-cross-compile-tarjan. But I am a bit stuck on how to continue from here on.

So far I have all the relvant code inside the shared directory:

- shared/src/main/scala

and two `Tarjan.scala` classes for both the JVM and the JS part here:

- js/src/main/scala/
- jvm/src/main/scala/

These are supposed to be public "interface classes" for both JVM and JS that just call methods from the shared library.

**js/src/main/scala/Tarjan.scala:**

```
import com.github.fbaierl.tarjan.{TarjanRecursive => lib}
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.{JSExport, JSExportTopLevel}

@JSExportTopLevel("Tarjan")
object Tarjan {
   @JSExport
   def tarjan[T](g: Map[T, List[T]]): Unit = lib.tarjan(g)
}
```

**jvm/src/main/scala/Tarjan.scala:**

```
import com.github.fbaierl.tarjan.{TarjanRecursive => lib}

object Tarjan {
  def tarjan[T](g: Map[T, List[T]]): Unit = lib.tarjan(g)
}
```

Is this generally the correct approach? Can I compile the project like that and publish to e.g. Sonatype?

Comment: Does your library need to be callable by JavaScript code directly, or do you intend to call it from Scala.js code? In the latter case, you do not even need `@JSExport(TopLevel)`. Exports are only needed if you need to call the methods from JavaScript code.

Comment: I intend to only call it from Scala.js, not from JavaScript. Just to be sure: I still need to cross-compile the project, right?

Comment: You do need to cross-compile the project, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of duplicating the "interface classes" for JS and JVM, you might want to use the scalajs-stubs library to be able to use `@JSExportTopLevel` and `@JSExport` in the shared code.

**shared/src/main/scala/Tarjan.scala:**

```
import com.github.fbaierl.tarjan.{TarjanRecursive => lib}
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.{JSExport, JSExportTopLevel}

@JSExportTopLevel("Tarjan")
object Tarjan {
  @JSExport
  def tarjan[T](g: Map[T, List[T]]): Unit = lib.tarjan(g)
}
```

**build.sbt:**

```
… .jvmSettings(
  libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %% "scalajs-stubs" % scalaJSVersion % "provided"
)
```

See "Exporting shared classes to JavaScript" at the bottom of https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/cross-build.html.